# Combining multiple conditions into one in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How can i shorten this code? I want to return all values except "abc" or "xyz" or "pqr"

```
return this.value != "abc" && this.value != "xyz"  && this.value != "pqr";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array:

```
return ["abc","xyz","pqr"].indexOf(this.value) == -1;
```

Or an object:

```
return !({"abc":1,"xyz":1,"pqr":1}).hasOwnProperty(this.value);
```

Comment: surprisingly the first statement gives an error in IE7 but works well in all other browsers

Comment: It seems that Internet Explorer has that method not yet implemented in version 7.

Comment: The object scheme does not work.
Consider this.value === 'toString'.
You can fix it by using hasOwnProperty instead

Answer (score 1):

2 most common ways are:

1. **regex**

   /^(abc|xyz|pqr)$/.test(this.value)
2. **object property lookup**

   this.value in ({'abc':1,'xyz':1,'pqr':1})

Note that regex-based solution (#1) will most definitely be slower than plain comparison (your version) or property lookup (#2).

Also, remember that **property lookup is not very reliable**, as it might report false positives for any key that's named the same as any of `Object.prototype.*` properties (e.g. "toString", "valueOf", etc.)