# Eliminating multiple OR conditions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Any recommendations on the most efficient way to check if the value of a variable can be one of multiple values instead of trying use a long if condition concatenated with a bunch of || (ORs)?

I saw something like `if (value in {'thing1':1, 'thing2':1, 'thing3':1})` but I'm not entirely sure how it works.

What is `in` considered as? An operator?

Comment: MDN docs about [**in operator**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/in) has lot of examples.

Comment: This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: http://interglacial.com/javascript_spec/a-11.html#a-11.8.7

Comment: use [jQuery.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray)

Answer (score 0):

If your values aren't strings, using `in` or the `indexOf` method shown in [Combining multiple conditions into one in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561257/combining-multiple-conditions-into-one-in-javascript) would be much less efficient that the chained OR tests, as both of these require that you convert the value to a string and do a string comparison. Comparing variables to their native values is almost always more efficient.

Assuming you're looking for values that don't match a pattern (like finding out if your test number is odd or a power of two), there are only a few things you can do to improve a chained OR test's speed. For example, testing for the most likely values first will improve overall performance; e.g., if X is more often 5 than 7, then:

```
if (X == 5 || X == 7)
```

will be more efficient in the long run than:

```
if (X == 7 || X == 5)
```

because the condition testing terminates when the expression becomes true.

Assuming your values *are* strings, the `in` and `indexOf` methods are not going to be any more efficient than a similarly constructed chained OR, and, given browser vagaries, may be worse. Unless you can determine a pattern in your values to test against, there is no getting around checking every single value until you find a match.