# Javascript syntax issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is the IF conditional logic correct? It works for test1 but not test2 or ""

```
      if($(this).attr("value") === ("test1" || "test2" || ""))
      {
          submitForm($(this).attr("value"));
      }
```

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want, then the logic isn't correct.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript: The prettiest way to compare one value against multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121395/javascript-the-prettiest-way-to-compare-one-value-against-multiple-values) or [A jQuery 'if' condition to check multiple values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597015/a-jquery-if-condition-to-check-multiple-values) or [Combining multiple conditions into one in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1561257/combining-multiple-conditions-into-one-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to test again each possible value:

```
if($(this).attr("value") === "test1" || $(this).attr("value") === "test2" || $(this).attr("value") === ""))
```

Cleaned with a temp variable:

```
var attribute = $(this).attr("value");
if(attribute === "test1" || attribute === "test2" || attribute === ""))
```

Alternative, you could use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) as shorthand:

```
if (["test1", "test2", ""].indexOf($(this).attr("value")) != -1)
```

Comment: No shortcut for this?

Comment: Use a variable for goodness sake.

Comment: @user2736012, of course. I was trying to relay the repetition.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene - Yes, there is a shortcut: write a function or use one of the _multiple_ alternatives suggested by the links in Bergi's comment.

Comment: I have yet to figure out if someone (@user2736012) is annoyed with the question, why waste their time responding.

Comment: @YetimworkBeyene - I don't see anything wrong with user2736012's suggestion to make things cleaner by using a variable.  Not sure why you think it shows annoyance.

Comment: Everyone can relax, the question was closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @jahroy what does goodness sake means? Happy? Don't assume i didn't do any research

Comment: "_Goodness sake_" doesn't mean annoyance.  It just says "_please_" with emphasis.  I don't need to assume you didn't do any research, your question speaks for itself.

Answer (score 1):

```
if($(this).attr("value") === ("test1" || "test2" || "")) {
    submitForm($(this).attr("value"));
}
```

What is going on here? The `OR ||` operator returns the first *truthy* value, so the returned value of `("test1" || "test2" || "")` is `"test1"`. In this case this expression is interpreted in this way:

```
(("test1" || "test2") || "")
```

The first expression evaluated is `"test1" || "test2"`, which returns `"test1"` since it is a truthy value. The second expression is `"test1" || ""`. Again it returns `"test1"`(moreover `""` is *falsy*).

A very fast way to write something similar to this is to search inside an array:

```
var acceptedValues = ["test1", "test2", ""];
if(acceptedValues.indexOf(this.value) != -1) submitForm(this.value);
```

In this simple operations jQuery is not needed!

Comment: For supporting older browser, you should use $.inArray()

Answer (score 0):

```
if($.inArray(this.value,['test1','test2','test3']) != -1){
    //...
}
```